# R dplyr - making 'count' function work in summarize_at chain

Tags: r, function, dplyr, pivot

Here is the data frame `starwars` from the `dplyr` library in R. I am trying to write an aggregated table using `dplyr` primarily using the `group_by_at` and `summarize_at` chain. I have defined the vectors `dimensionsVec`, `measuresVec`, and functions. The goal is to use all three vectors in the `dplyr` chain which is assigned to the data frame `pivotData`.

Unfortunately, the `count = length` argument doesn't work when trying to spit out the data frame after running `pivotData`. It may be due to the `na.rm = TRUE` statement. So basically, everything works except for the `count = length` argument in functions. You can find that out by commenting out the `count = length` part of the `functions vector.

Would anybody be able to help me? Thanks so much for your help!

Code snippet below

```
library(dplyr)

data <- starwars

dimensionsVec <- c("skin_color", "eye_color")
measuresVec <- c("height", "mass")

functions <- c(count = "length", 
               mean = "mean", 
               sum = "sum", 
               median = "median", 
               max = "max", 
               min = "min")

funsList <- lapply(functions, match.fun)
names(funsList) <- functions

pivotData <- data %>%
  group_by_at(vars(dimensionsVec)) %>%
  summarize_at(vars(measuresVec), funsList, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  collect()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to be careful about the functions you are passing. You can't add the `na.rm = TRUE` parameter to `summarize_at` unless it can be passed to all the functions in your list. However, if you pass `na.rm = TRUE` to `length`, it will throw an error.

One way round this is to create a wrapper around `length` that takes an `na.rm` parameter:

```r
funsList <- list(count = function(x, na.rm) length(x),
                 mean = mean,
                 sum = sum, 
                 median = median, 
                 max = max, 
                 min = min)
```

(Note that you can use unquoted function names directly rather than having them all as character strings and using `match.fun`)

This approach works, but it reveals an additional problem in your code. Some of the groups you are summarizing have no non-NA entries, so you are effectively doing `min(NA, na.rm = TRUE)` on some groups. This causes a warning and returns an `Inf` instead of an `NA` in the result that you probably don't want. You similarly get an unwanted `-Inf` with `max` and `NaN` from `mean` and `median`.

The solution is to be specific about what you want each function to do in this scenario. For example, you can create a little function that takes your summary functions as an argument and returns an NA-safe version of them:

```r
handle_NA <- function(func) 
{
  function(x) if(all(is.na(x))) NA else func(x, na.rm = TRUE) 
}
```

This allows you to create a safe `funsList` like so:

```
funsList <- list(count = length,
                 mean = handle_NA(mean),
                 sum = handle_NA(sum),
                 median = handle_NA(median), 
                 max = handle_NA(max), 
                 min = handle_NA(min))

data %>%
  group_by(across(all_of(dimensionsVec))) %>%
  summarize(across(all_of(measuresVec), funsList), .groups = "drop")
#> # A tibble: 53 x 14
#>    skin_color eye_color height_count height_mean height_sum height_median
#>    <chr>      <chr>            <int>       <dbl>      <int>         <dbl>
#>  1 blue       blue                 1        196         196          196 
#>  2 blue       hazel                1        178         178          178 
#>  3 blue, grey yellow               2        116.        231          116.
#>  4 brown      blue                 1        234         234          234 
#>  5 brown      brown                2        130.        259          130.
#>  6 brown      yellow               1        198         198          198 
#>  7 brown mot~ orange               1        180         180          180 
#>  8 brown, wh~ green, y~            1        216         216          216 
#>  9 dark       blue                 1        184         184          184 
#> 10 dark       brown                4        183.        733          184 
#> # ... with 43 more rows, and 8 more variables: height_max <int>,
#> #   height_min <int>, mass_count <int>, mass_mean <dbl>, mass_sum <dbl>,
#> #   mass_median <dbl>, mass_max <dbl>, mass_min <dbl>
```

Note that the scoped verbs `summarize_at` and `group_by_at` have been superseded by using `across`, so I have switched to the more modern syntax.